# How to use on_presence_update event from discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, gateway

I've been trying to be able to asynchronously listen for events sent by discord to indicate a user's change of activity status (for example, if someone is listening to music on discord, it would track changes to the music they're listening to as they listen through a playlist, or it would trigger an event if the user starts playing a game)

I'm trying to do this using a discord bot, which would track this data for members of a given server (of which this bot is a part of, with administrative permissions). I enabled the privileged intents for the bot on the developer portal, since the on_presense_update event requires this. In my code, I specified the intents I want to listen to like this:

`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', itents=intents)`

However, my event listener never picks up any changes to a user's presence (specifically, activity status updates); the following code never runs:

`@client.event
async def on_presence_update(before, after):
       #do something`

Am I implementing this incorrectly, or am I using the wrong intent to accomplish what I'm trying to?

Please let me know if I'm not sharing the right details--I'm quite new to discord.py, and the world of intents and gateways in general!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though `on_presence_update()` may be a deprecated method. Try using `on_member_update()` instead, as per the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_update).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that recently is facing this issue, on my case at least the problem was that this feature is only available after Discord.py 2.0+ which needs Python 3.8+

Until Python 3.7 you can only install Discord.py 1.7.x which means `on_presence_update` does not work, so the solution is just update your python and discord.py pkg.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is inaccurate

on_presence_update() is not deprecated.

[As seen here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#presence-updates-now-have-a-separate-event) it was new on v2.0:

> Presence updates (changes in member’s status and activity) now have a separate on_presence_update() event. on_member_update() event is now only called on member updates (changes in nickname, role, pending status, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is my code using on_presence_update:

```py
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(before, after):
    if str(before.activity) != str(after.activity):           #logging you member's activities
        channel = await client.fetch_channel('channel_id')    #insert you logging channel ID here
        channel.send(f"""{after}'s activity changed from 
{before.activity} to {after.activity}""")
    
    if str(before.status) != str(after.status):               #logging your member's status
        channel = await client.fetch_channel('channel_id')    #insert you logging channel ID here
        channel.send(f"""{after}'s status changed from
{before.status} to {after.status}""")
```

So give it a try and if it doesn't work, you maybe have to give all intents:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

Hope this can help you even after one year..

(I found this solution at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_presence_update#members))